# Python - Создание MACcode Finder

Tags: python, поиск, пути

Здравствуйте! Недавно (вчера), поднимал вопрос о запуске cmd.exe. Я занимаюсь спец-заказом министерства правды, и разрабатываю (фактически стилер) MAC Finder. После проблемы запуска cmd возникла следующая проблема - поиск этой самой cmd, и определение ОС компьютера.
Код стилера (фрагмент отвечающий за поиск mac через arp -a) такой:

```
try:
    with open(unc_cod+'mc', 'wb', 0) as file:
        subprocess.run(r'c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /C arp -a',  stdout=file, check=True)
except:
    print('''An Error Ocured while installing: Reading from / finding cmd.exe (code 0x0001). Please contact developer to have a support. Press Enter to exit.''')
    input()
```

Так, как на разных компьютерах cmd.exe (и система в целом) стоит на разных дисках, то появилась необходимость поиска самого файла cmd.exe перебором английских букв, и подставлением их под путь (переменная:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe, где переменная - буква), дабы найти путь к cmd exe, и использовать его дальше (также было бы не плохо узнавать ОСь, и если это Виндовс - продолжать). Возможно интернет сейшельский, возможно не правильно искал, но находил все, кроме искомого. Опыта не имею, поэтому и прошу у вас помощь. Дополнение: От себя написал на скорую руку код (есесно он не работает), его суть в том, что он перебирает все возможные буквы, подставляет их под путь, и в случае успеха выводит успешный адрес файла:

```
import os
spk =['c','d','e','a','b','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
i3 = 0
for chr in range(26):
    chr = spk[i3]
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r''+ str(chr)+':\Windows\System32\''):
        #print(files)
        file_name = 'cmd.exe'
        for name in files:
            if name == file_name:
                print (os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root, name)))
                break
```

Comment: Чего? Какая у вас конечная цель этого фрагмента? Определить семейство и версию ОС? Найти бинарник вы можете CLI командой `where` - `where cmd`.

Comment: @m9_psy какой смысл использовать CLI команды, когда нужно использовать python?

Comment: @KitScribe, такой, что задача программиста - решить какую-то техническую проблему, а не изобретать колесо. Данный вопрос и оба ответа - именно такое колесо, причем вместо спиц у него грабли.
Если нужно узнать MAC тачки - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159137/getting-mac-address
Если нужно узнать, где находится бинарник и путь к бинарнику есть в переменной PATH (то есть команда пускается без указания полного пути) - `where <binname>`
Если нужно запустить команду `arp` как будто из оболочки - `subprocess.run(["arp", "-a"], stdout=sys.stdout, shell=True)`

Comment: @m9_psy спасибо, буду в курсе таких фичей. Я всего лишь переделал реализацию автора, мне же это без надобности пока что

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import string
import os
import sys

def find_file(file: str, pach='{}:%s%s' % (os.sep, os.path.join('Windows', 'System32'))):
    if sys.platform == 'win32':
        for folder in map(pach.format, string.ascii_uppercase):
            for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder):
                for f in files:
                    if f == file:
                        return os.path.join(root, file)

print(find_file('cmd.exe'))
>>> C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую проверить. На диске C все нашел, попробую на других дисках.

Answer (score 1):

Модифицировал ваш вчерашний вариант.

Проверьте:

```
import subprocess
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()
name = str(now) + '_mac-list.bin'

disks =['c','d','e','a','b','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']

for disk in disks:
    try:
        with open(name, 'wb', 0) as file:
            subprocess.run(disk + ':\windows\system32\cmd.exe /' + disk.upper() + ' arp -a', stdout=file, check=True)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: Выдает временную ошибку: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '2017-04-11 14:33:46.052862_mac-list.bin'

Comment: Внизу уже описали работающий вариант, спасибо.